# How do you dynamically load default HTML5 video thumbnails in Android WebView?

Tags: android-studio, webview, html5-video

I've just recently started using Android Studio for the first time to develop a mobile app that simply loads my website and displays it. I added a WebView with WebSettings that enable JavaScript among other things and it works! However, video thumbnails do not display. Instead an ugly gray placeholder play button image is used. How do I make it so that the video thumbnails load like they would on desktop devices, or even in mobile browsers (because they do display there as well)?

I'm not entirely sure whether or not to include code in this question but I will share anyway :P

Here's the relevant snippets of the MainActivity.java file:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com"); //My domain
}
}
```

So basically, it's either the `preload="metadata"` in my website's code or some equivalent attribute or CSS property that messes with Android WebView's autogeneration of video thumbnails, or it's because of my extreme newbieness to the whole Android app development thing. I'm willing to bet on the latter.

Also as a side question, should I store thumbnails on my server instead of having everyone's browsers load the 1st frame of every video every time?

Thanks in advance :)